# How to change the chart color in google sheets when number below zero

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have a line chart in google sheets and my values could be below zero, I want to know if in google sheets I can change the color when those values are less than zero.

What I have is this chart with one color:

[image: ROI x Monthly Breakdown]

Comment: you can use a [style column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) to change the color of the line for a specific segment / point -- add a column after the value column with the color the value should be --  if you could share a sample of the code it would be easier to help...

Comment: that is not possible via standard means